# Status code for invalid, but optional, credentials

Tags: rest, authentication

We are designing a RESTful backend service that lists messages in two modes: authenticated and unauthenticated. If the request is authenticated (i.e., it includes an `Authorization` header) then both private and public messages should be displayed. If the request is unauthenticated, then only public messages should be displayed.

What is the RESTful way of dealing with requests that contain an `Authorization` header, but with expired credentials?

1. List only public messages;
2. Return 401, as if the credentials were invalid;
3. Another status code; which one?

I am leaning towards 401, but this is a bit confusing to the front-end, as it indicates that credentials are required, whereas in our case they are optional. Is there some kind of known REST practice for "failed optional authentication"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can require a different URL if the caller wants to get private messages. REST responses should generally be the same for a given URL, as that assumption will simplify a lot of things, such as this authentication concern. Something like this will work:

```
/messages?private=true # requires auth
/messages # doesn't require auth
```

Now you can return 401 if `private=true` and credentials are invalid/expired, whereas the credentials may be ignored if private is false/omitted. This will remove any ambiguity.